# Subscripts in ylim of likert plot

Tags: r, plot, substring

I am trying to plot a likert scale plot similar to one here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/plotting-likert-scales/

Using the instructions at the link above, I was able to plot it. However, I want to display certain text (i.e., subscripts) on y axis.

I need to plot them like `a_[1x] b_[2x] c_[3x]` where I have 3 different characters (a, b, and c) displaying subscripts 1x, 2x and 3x respectively.

First, I have tried this:

```
ylim= c("a_1x","b_2x","c_3x")
```

This works fine, but subscripts in the y axes do not appear. I actually need to plot them like `a_[1x] b_[2x] c_[3x]`

I have also tried this:

```
ylim= c(expression('a'[1x]),expression('b'[2x]),expression('c'[3x]))
```

But, this produces the following error when I try to plot it.

```
Error in diff(range(as.numeric(limits))) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

This is the code generating the likert plot.

```
likert(sgbar.likert,
       ylim = yLabels, ## Here yLabels need to contain expression somehow?
       xlab="Percentage",
       main="Example Diverging Stacked Bar Chart for Likert Scale",
       BrewerPaletteName="Blues",
       sub="Likert Scale")
```

**Edit:**

Here is the full code if you guys want to reproduce the issue and test:

```
set.seed(1234)
library(e1071)
probs <- cbind(c(.4,.2/3,.2/3,.2/3,.4),c(.1/4,.1/4,.9,.1/4,.1/4),c(.2,.2,.2,.2,.2))
my.n <- 100
my.len <- ncol(probs)*my.n
raw <- matrix(NA,nrow=my.len,ncol=2)
raw <- NULL
for(i in 1:ncol(probs)){
raw <- rbind(raw, cbind(i,rdiscrete(my.n,probs=probs[,i],values=1:5)))
}

r <- data.frame( cbind(
as.numeric( row.names( tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], mean) ) ),
tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], mean),
tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], mean) + sqrt( tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], var)/tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], length) ) * qnorm(1-.05/2,0,1),
tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], mean) - sqrt( tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], var)/tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], length) ) * qnorm(1-.05/2,0,1)
))
names(r) <- c("group","mean","ll","ul")

gbar <- tapply(raw[,2], list(raw[,2], raw[,1]), length)

sgbar <- data.frame( cbind(c(1:max(unique(raw[,1]))),t(gbar)) )

sgbar.likert<- sgbar[,2:6]


require(grid)
require(lattice)
require(latticeExtra)
require(HH)
sgbar.likert<- sgbar[,2:6]

yLabels = c("a_1x","b_2x","c_3x") # this works fine but it does not show expressions.
#yLabels = c(expression(a[1*x]),expression(b[2*x]),expression(c[3*x])) # this causes the error above

likert(sgbar.likert,
       ylim = yLabels, ## Here yLabels need to contain expression somehow?
       xlab="Percentage",
       main="Example Diverging Stacked Bar Chart for Likert Scale",
       BrewerPaletteName="Blues",
       sub="Likert Scale")
```

**The plot looks like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `ggplot`usually do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(S.ID, data = df) + scale_x_discrete(labels = c(expression(a[1*x]),expression(b[2*x]),expression(c[3*x])))
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Sorry that I didn't take a closer look before, but since the `likert` plot uses `lattice` instead of `ggplot2`, the method of tick labels modification is different from what I gave you above.

But again, `ylim` is not the correct way to modify the label. It actually can accept character vector, I found out, but it cannot evaluate the expression.

So, you should use `scales`, which is the general argument to determine how the axis is drawn (including limit, ticks, labels) and set the appropriate component for y axis.

```
yLabels = c(expression(a[1*x]),expression(b[2*x]),expression(c[3*x]))
likert(sgbar.likert,
       scales = list(y = list(labels = yLabels)),
       xlab="Percentage",
       main="Example Diverging Stacked Bar Chart for Likert Scale",
       BrewerPaletteName="Blues",
       sub="Likert Scale")
```

[image]

SIDE NOTE: Thanks for editing the question. It gave me clearer idea on the real issue and it was easier to find the solution. As always, providing reproducible example is the best way to ask a question and get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am not sure about your suggestion. Should I add "+ scale_y_discrete(labels = c(expression(a[1*x]),expression(b[2*x]),expression(c[3*x])))" after likert or something else? When I try "ylim = c(expression(a[1*x]),expression(b[2*x]),expression(c[3*x]))", It did not work, the same error was produced again: Error in diff(range(as.numeric(limits))) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'. Also, If I use "ylim = c("a_1x","b_2x","c_3x")", it works fine but it does not show the expressions.

Comment: I appreciate for your help. I was  wondering if there is a way to show percentage in the plot? Just like this one: https://strengejacke.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/sjplotlikert2.png